# WinRT CoreDispatcher RunAsync and closures

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, dispatcher, synchronizationcontext

The WinRT CoreDispatcher has the RunAsync method which, actually doesn't take a state variable.

Translation: Every single notification that happens by posting to the Dispatcher in most common scenarios ends up in an allocation internally due to the closure. Its quite concerning that a simple and important design was overlooked.

Eg: A simple common example implementing an INotifyPropertyChanged requires a method that ends up something like this:

```
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(
[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                // Check access first, and then at some point pass it along.
                Dispatcher.RunAsync(() => 
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
            }
    }
```

Now, every time a simple prop changed notification is called, a new class is allocated by the compiler behind the scenes, which is terrible for a lot of notifications. This makes falling back to SynchronizationContext.Post, a more efficient option when there are lot of notifications considering it has a state variable that the handler, and propertyName can be passed along with.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how to work with the Dispatcher in this scenario would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about it. Using a closure is likely to be just fine; I doubt you'll observe any significant performance decrease.

Note that in other cases where you *can* pass parameters to the invoked method, you still wind up with an allocation. At a minimum, an `object[]` has to be allocated to contain the parameters. In addition, value type parameters wind up having to be boxed: more allocations.

So it seems to me that a closure is at worst the same, and in some scenarios can be more efficient allocation-wise, since value types don't have to be boxed in that scenario.

If, against all odds, you do find yourself in a scenario where the allocations are hurting your performance, you can implement your own closure explicitly and reuse the instance. I.e. create a class that is explicitly used, which contains any variables that would normally be captured, and which contains the code you want to execute. Then allocate one of those (or several, in a pool) and reuse the instance(s) for each invocation.

But really, I doubt you'll ever find a compelling reason to go to all that trouble.

Comment: I see your point. I guess using a pool seems to be the best idea in this case. Thanks, didn't think a pool for whatever reason. I'm looking at a scenario of a log view served with INotifyPropertyChanged handlers. So, hundreds of events in per sec. :)

Comment: FWIW, 100's of events per second is basically nothing for a modern PC and .NET. Even 1000/second would not tax the computer. At that rate, I can pretty much _guarantee_ that you won't experience any significant performance issues due to the use of closures for handling each event.

Comment: No doubt even thousands of events are barely anything. But its just the logger. Logging 100s of events implying 100s of taxing operations already running. :) 

Anyhow, a generic object state would still be a lot more efficient. Since an Action<T>, T state, combined with a Tuple-like struct for multiple params should make it through with zero allocation on the heap. If only.

Comment: _"Logging 100s of events implying 100s of taxing operations already running."_ That just reinforces my point. In the context of these events, the single allocation (and eventual collection...the allocation itself is actually essentially free while the cost, however inconsequential, comes when it's time to do a GC) just isn't something that will matter. Remember, an `Action<T>` is an object too, and again passing value types without strongly-typed containers means boxing (more allocations). .NET is designed to handle lots of allocations; don't worry about it until you have proof you need to.